# В каком месте страницы лучше подключать js-файлы?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Я обычно подключаю js в head. Но в Bootstrap это всё подключается в конце... Наверное, в этом есть какой-то смысл? Может кто знает?

Answer (score 12):

Лучше подключать JavaScript в конце, т.к. время загрузки скриптов можно потратить с пользой на оформление страницы, что собственно bootstrap и делает. Многие браузеры отрисовывают контент по мере загрузки страницы, и поместив подключение JS инклюдов в конец, мы тем самым ускоряем прорисовку стилей и всего что подключено до этого.

Answer (score 5):

стандартное правило, если подключать javaScript вначале то (в общем случае, но не всегда) body не будет отрисовываться, пока не выполнится подключаемый js скрипт. потому рекомендуется подключать js в конце. это азбука. и ей следуют создатели bootstrap

при выполнении браузером html страницы браузер выполняет ее построчно. как только встречается js (например линк на файл который на 4 сек заставит браузер "висеть") он выполняется, и только после этого идет чтение следующей строки html. потому разумнее сначала дать браузеру выполнять все body и лишь потом заставлять выполнять js

[html5rocks учебник](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Scripts)

Comment: Приведите ссылку на оф. документацию. Иначе буду вынужден голосовать против ответа.

Comment: 2 GrayHoax. я не говорил что это спецификация w3c. я говорил что это некое общепринятое стандартное правило. азбука. нашел Вам линк, пожалуйста. [html5rocks учебник](http://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#Scripts)

Comment: Я говорил про утверждение `если подключать javaScript вначале то body не будет отрисовываться, пока не выполнятся все js скрипты`, мне не понятно с чего Вы это взяли.

Comment: 2 GrayHoax. Вы правы. я написал это очень обще. если в подключаемом в head js встретиться alert (к примеру) то тогда наша страница зависнет. в случае когда мы используем 'async' браузер продолжит отрисовку. надо бы поправить...

Comment: Хорошо, что Вы исправили свой ответ. Не стоит вводить людей в заблуждение.

Comment: 2 GrayHoax. Вам тоже спасибо. это был мой первый ответ. очень здорово что на ресурсе настолько серьезно относятся к происходящему.

Comment: @GrayHoax, всё там правильно было. Браузер не отобразит продолжение страницы до тех пор, пока не скачает и не выполнит скрипт, если он не помечен атрибутами async и/или defer (да и то с оговорками). В качестве оптимизации, он может продолжить парсинг, но это чисто внутренности браузера, а показать он ничего не должен, как, впрочем, и парсить, поскольку скрипты могут выполнять всякие document.write или чтение dom'а.

Comment: Уточнение - ждать будет только часть после скрипта, часть перед вполне может быть отображена. Но в случае с head, частью после окажется всё body.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну вот Вы же сами и говорите `В качестве оптимизации, он может продолжить парсинг` так что правка в тему

Comment: Против правки в текущем виде ничего не имею (тем более, атрибуты под неё тоже попадают), но по правилам парсинга браузер должен ждать. Он вообще не знает, будет ли следующий кусок html-разметкой. Там банально может оказаться вывод комментария или тега `plaintext`, или `script` - и всё, кусок дальше - больше не разметка. Если скрипт не помечен особым образом, то вся деятельность браузера по обработке дальнейшего содержимого, если она вообще делается, должна быть скрыта и от скрипта, и от пользователя, потому что её как бы нет - её нет по спецификации.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен. спасибо за коммент.

Answer (score 2):

> К сожалению, браузеры блокируют дальнейшую отрисовку страницы, пока
>   это все происходит. Еще со времен «первого века веба» это обусловлено
>   DOM API, который позволяет строкам добавляться к содержимому, которое
>   пережовывает парсер, например с помощью document.write. Более
>   современные браузеры продолжат сканировать и парсить документ в
>   фоновом режиме и загружать нужный сторонний контент (js, картинки, css
>   и т.д.), но отрисовка по-прежнему будет блокирована.
>
> Вот почему гуру и специалисты производительности советуют размещать
>   элементы script в конце документа, потому что это блокирует меньше
>   всего контента.

Из статьи на хабре http://habrahabr.ru/post/182310/ возможно именно поэтому.