# Подключение скриптов в хэдере и футере

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день. Видел во многих проектах подключение скриптов в хедере и футере. Насколько этот подход считается правильным и целесообразным? Интересно профессиональное мнение.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448715/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-bootstrap-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-js-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5

Comment: а что Вам мешает провести эксперимент?